# Mono not executing VS compiled 4.5 .NET API exe with Azure reference

Tags: c#, .net, azure, ubuntu, mono

I have a Linux/ubuntu Trusty64 virtual machine through virtual box manager. I'm trying to run a VS 2015 compiled .NET4.5 Web API exe with Azure storage reference through Mono. I have the Exe and EXE.Config file in the app folder. When I give the mono command it comes back saying

Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, version=7.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried putting the file Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll in the exe's folder?

Comment: what does `does not work` mean? does it throw the same error or a new one?

Comment: Sorry, will be more specific moving forward. It throws the same error.  The other way I figured we can do this, is compiling the cs file with gmcs/mcs and refer all these dll's as reference. However, by that way it totally refuses to see the app.config file in the folder. At present all the dll's and the config and exe are in the same folder.

Comment: Update: Here is how I did it, I upgraded my .NET code into a 5.0 console package template. Made sure it was DNX 5.0 core compliant code and made the below dockerfile in the Ubuntu virtual machine at the solution level of the project.                                                                                                                     FROM microsoft/aspnet

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app/src/"Projectname"

RUN ["dnu","restore"]

ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "run"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it, I upgraded my .NET code into a 5.0 console package template. Made sure it was DNX 5.0 core compliant code and made the below dockerfile in the Ubuntu virtual machine at the solution level of the project.                   FROM microsoft/aspnet                                                           COPY .  /app                                                                  WORKDIR /app/src/"Projectname"                                                   RUN ["dnu","restore"]                                                         ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "run"]